# setInterval as part of foreach loop in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm building a hybrid app and am using Nuxt JS / Vue JS. I have native notifications, and the ability to add multiple "URLs" which do GET requests to their URL, they then fetch back some text.

The idea is, I might want URL 1 to fetch some text every 10 seconds, and URL 2 to fetch every minute.

I'm trying to plug in my `setInterval` using a variable, however, each variable needs a unique key so that they don't conflict and all run at the same time, the following is my code, and I'm trying to utilise the key to create a unique variable:

```
/**
 * Auto fetch notifications
 */
autoFetchNotifications() {
  let self = this
  Object.keys(this.dataUrls).forEach(function(key, index) {
    var interval;
    var intervalCombined = interval + key
    if (parseInt(self.$refs.fetch[key].innerText) != 0) {
      if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        intervalCombined = setInterval(() => {
          self.fetchNotifications()
          console.log('Running -> ' + parseInt(self.$refs.fetch[key].innerText))
          clearInterval(intervalCombined)
        }, parseInt(self.$refs.fetch[key].innerText))
      }
    }
  })
}
```

I've tried setting a variable in `data()` and referencing:

```
self.intervalCombined = setInterval(() => {
  self.fetchNotifications()
  clearInterval(self.intervalCombined)
}, parseInt(self.$refs.fetch[key].innerText))
```

However, this will mean that all of my setInterval functions will reference the same variable, so this isn't great as they'll all get cleared at the same time and this will mean all notifications run together.

Some context:

- `parseInt(self.$refs.fetch[key].innerText)` is a Number, in ms how long before it should run.
- `this.dataUrls` is an array of objects, not sure if I need to use my `self` on this bit where it's doing the forEach., `this.dataUrls` is pulled from localStorage.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the way with binding the interval objects to the components context is a way to go. You can define variables and objects on the components context outside of the data function as well. Is `intervalCombined` already a unique name for the interval object? Can't you just `self[intervalCombined] = setInterval() => ....` save each intervall on the context like that?

Comment: This seems to work, however, the `setInterval` seems to run quicker, and quicker, every time the page is reloaded or changed. `autoFetchNotifications` runs on page load

Comment: You could use the component lifecycle callbacks then `beforeUpdate()` and/or `beforeDestroy()` then in order to clear out all intervalls. Maybe this works? https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeUpdate, https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeDestroy